# pm-utils not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: suspend, hibernate, pm-utils

`/etc/pm/sleep.d/00_update` has these permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  148 oct 28 09:46 00_update
```

and the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
  hibernate|suspend)
    echo suspended >> ~/.state
    ;;
  thaw|resume)
    echo awake >> ~/.state
    ;;
esac
```

but nothing happens after suspending, hibernating or restarting the system.

In the folder there are other files, namely:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  210 may 15  2014 10_grub-common
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  660 dic  6  2013 10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1260 may 23  2012 novatel_3g_suspend
```

Is there any additional step in order to make `00_update` run properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `bash` script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/00_update` is run as the `root` user, `~/.state` means something other than your home directory.

Replace both occurrences of `~/.state` with the absolute path, something like `/home/w3/.state` (YMMV).

Also, if you use an encrypted home directory, there will be times when it is not mounted (when you are not logged in), so consider writing your file into `/tmp`.

Comment: I feel so stupid...

Comment: While this was just to test functioning, my interest is in synchronizing repositories with Mercurial after leaving the workplace. However, having solved the directories issue, now the `hg push` seems to get stuck, this message is stored in a log file: nothing changed
`pushing to https://user:***@bitbucket.org/user/repository` and nothing else happens, as if the internet connection would be lost. Actually, the computer does not complete suspension.

Comment: (The very same command works fine from the command line, of course.)

Comment: Ask a 2nd question about `hg push` problem in a question of its own.

Comment: Please, find it here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843690/pm-utils-commands-not-working-because-wifi-goes-down-before